# .NET 3.5 unexpected error and include

Tags: asp.net, .net, json.net

I'm working on a .NET 2.0 C# project using the Newtonsoft.JSON library. When i check the web.config file all assemblies refer to the 2.0 version.

However when i deploy on the server i get the following error :

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


Line 21:     }
Line 22: 
Line 23:     Dictionary<string, string> config = JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jason);
Line 24: 
Line 25:     if (Request.Form["login"] == config["adminLogin"] && FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Request.Form["password"], "sha1") == config["adminPass"])


Source File: c:\Website\WSRecrut\Test\ConnectionPost.aspx    Line: 23

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateDictionaryWrapper(Object dictionary) in D:\Newtonsoft\Projects\Json\trunk\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionUtils.cs:422
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue) in D:\Newtonsoft\Projects\Json\trunk\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:223
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in D:\Newtonsoft\Projects\Json\trunk\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:169
   Newtonsoft.Json.JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters) in D:\Newtonsoft\Projects\Json\trunk\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JavaScriptConvert.cs:512
   Newtonsoft.Json.JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, JsonConverter[] converters) in D:\Newtonsoft\Projects\Json\trunk\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JavaScriptConvert.cs:485
   Newtonsoft.Json.JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(String value) in D:\Newtonsoft\Projects\Json\trunk\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JavaScriptConvert.cs:457
   ASP.connectionpost_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Website\WSRecrut\Test\ConnectionPost.aspx:23
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +2113547
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +24
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +26
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +121
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +22
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1896
```

Does anybody have an idea ? Where can that assembly on 3.5 could come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've included the wrong `NewtonSoft.Json.dll` library. There's multiple assemblies - only one of which supports .NET 2.0.

If you have Reflector/JustDecompile, you can verify that it has an internal class `Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.LinqBridge` - that's what allows it to get away with not using the `System.Core` LINQ methods.

The File Details also have .NET 2.0 in the description.

Comment: Mark, i'm using the right .NET 2.0 Newtonsoft Library. When compiled with visual studio 2008 targetting .NET 2.0 no error is shown.

Comment: Actually the Newtonsoft Library was old, when i switched to the latest 2.0 comptabile all worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1, Parser Error Message: Could not load  file or assembly  'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  or one of its dependencies. The system  cannot find  the file  specified.

I would recommend you invest whether .NET Framework 3.5 is installed on your goal machine or not. You could download a verification tool to verify .NET Framework states on your goal machine. You could click following link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

2, WRN: Assembly binding  logging is turned  OFF.

To enable  assembly bind  failure logging, set  the registry  value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure  logging.

To turn this feature off, remove the registry value

If it does not work, you could modify  the registry on the basis of the error information.

You could follow the following steps one by one.

1, open ‘Run’

2, type ‘regedit’

3, backup your registry

4, search the key in Registry

5, modify its value on basis of error information

Comment: Thanks, i know that .NET 3.5 is not installed on the target server. That's why i wrote a .NET 2.0 project.

Answer (score 1):

another route to getting this data is to look at the details of the exception... you'll need to ensure debugger is running and stop on the exception to look at the details.

All of this seems to be either a configuration problem (which can be all about the details -- double check everything like the output from "aspnet_regiis -lk"), or the .NET installation has been corrupted (but this seems a lot less likely).

Else ,

The “'System.Web.Extensions” is the Strong Named assembly that should be installed in GAC, the file not found issue should not caused by the relative path problem of the sub directory. In my opinion, the problem is the AJAX 1.0 extension is not installed on the server.

To solve this issue, we can remove the “1.0.61025.0” version “System.Web.Extensions” assembly from the “assemblies” section. As you said, after doing that, the LINQ assembly not found issue appears. For this issue, I would recommend checking if .NET Framework 3.5 installed on the Server.

Comment: I don't use Ajax but thanks anyway. I will remove all assemblies to test.